# What would be the standard errors of this transformed regression model, given that I know the standard errors of the original model

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis

Say I have the following regression model:

$\ln\left(\dfrac{y_i}{x_{2i}}\right)=\alpha_1+\alpha_2\ln(x_{2i}) + \alpha_3\ln(x_{3i}) +e_i$

where I know the values of the regression coefficients and standard errors.

Now, I can rewrite the model as:

$\ln(y_i)=\beta_1+\beta_2\ln(x_{2i}) + \beta_3\ln(x_{3i}) +e_i$

where $\beta_1=\alpha_1$, $\beta_2=\alpha_2+1$, and $\beta_3=\alpha_3$.

How do I compute the standard errors for the new model, given that I know what they are for the original model? I believe they are just the same? But I am not sure... if someone could explain to me that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you get rid of the $x_{2i}$ when you rewrote the model? Is there an implied distribution for $y_i$? (This looks like a Poisson regression.)